# pandas.read_csv of a gzip file within a zipped directory

Tags: pandas, ascii, gzip, zip

I would like to use pandas.read_csv to open a gzip file (.asc.gz) within a zipped directory (.zip). Is there an easy way to do this?

This code doesn't work:

csv = pd.read_csv(r'C:\folder.zip\file.asc.gz') // can't find the file

This code does work (however, it requires me to unzip the folder, which I want to avoid because my dataset currently contains thousands of zipped folders):

csv = pd.read_csv(r'C:\folder\file.asc.gz')

Is there an easy way to do this? I have tried using a combination of zipfile.Zipfile and read_csv, but have been unsuccessful (I think partly due to the fact that this is an ascii file as well)

Comment: Any possibility to share example of a file that we can work on it? Or share the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the followings might help.

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.gz', compression='gzip')
```

OR

```
import gzip
file=gzip.open('filename.gz','rb')
content=file.read()
```